# NO ME MUESTRA EL ALERT DESPUES DE ENVIAR DATOS PORQUE SERA?

Tags: php, html

[image: Imagen del codigo]

No me muestra los mensajes que están dentro del if de php, es como que si no tomase los valores del boton enviar. Agreadezco si alguien me da una mano

Comment: Lectura recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Comment: será el capslock?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Construí tu código e Hice pruebas, el detalle es que no estás incluyendo comillas y comilla simple para concatenar una variable php dentro de una sentencia JS.

Respondiendo puntualmente a tu pregunta, intenta con esto:

```
echo "<script> alert ('".$nombre." Tiene Estudios Secundarios');</script>";
```

Tambien vi que estás enviando el formulario al mismo archivo, bien puedes usar:
`<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">` o `<form action="form.php">` pero debes recibir las variables utilizando **$_GET** en lugar de **$_POST**

Es más sencillo validar si existe la variable por eso sustituí `if($check1=="Sin estudios"){}`  por `if(isset($_GET['check1'])){}` Ya que es un input de tipo Check (True/False) y es mejor saber si está definido o no,en lugar de averiguar su valor

El código que probé fue este:

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
    <label for="Nombre">Ingrese el nombre de la persona
        <input type="text" name="Nombre" id="Nombre">
    </label>
    <br>
    <label for="name">No Tiene Estudios
        <input type="checkbox" name="check1" id="chek1" value="Sin estudios"> 
    </label>
    <br>
    <label for="chek2">Estudios Primarios
        <input type="checkbox" name="check2" id="chek2" value="Estudios Primarios"> 
    </label>
    <br>
    <label for="chek3">Estudios Secundarios
        <input type="checkbox" name="check3" id="chek3" value="Estudios Secundarios"> 
    </label>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" name="Enviar" value="Enviar" id="Enviar">
</form>

<?php
    if(isset($_GET['Enviar'])){
        $nombre=$_GET['Nombre'];
        if(isset($_GET['check1'])){ 
            echo "<script> alert ('".$nombre." No tiene Estudios');</script>";
        }

        else if(isset($_GET['check2'])){  
            echo "<script> alert ('".$nombre." Tiene Estudios Primarios');</script>";
        }

        else if(isset($_GET['check3'])){
            echo "<script> alert ('".$nombre." Tiene Estudios Secundarios');</script>";
        } 
    }
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

te dejo un código que funciona para esta tarea.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form action="scripts.php" method="post">
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" id="resultado" name="resultado" value="1">
            <label for="resultado">Seleccione este checkbox</label>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" name="sendForm" value="Enviar" />
    </form>
    <script></script>
    <?php
    if (isset($_POST['sendForm'])) {
        if (isset($_POST['resultado']) && $_POST['resultado'] == '1')

            echo '<script>alert("Gracias por obedecer")</script>';
        else
            echo '<script>alert("Usted es un insurrecto")</script>';
    }
    ?>
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

El botón debe ser de tipo submit para que realice la acción de enviar el formulario.

```
<input type="submit" name="enviar" value="Enviar" />
```

Por otro lado, para que podamos responderte mejor, en futuras ocasiones publica el código como código con el boton {} y no como una imagen, para poder así copiarlo y evaluar el problema mas rápido.